# Static file storage and server hosting - Django

Tags: python, django, deployment, server

I am new to server side operations and have a personal project that I am building. I am running Python3, Django2 with mysql (which will be changed to postgres for live usage) and currently have my static files stored inside the virtualenv on my local drive. It's also built locally on Ubuntu 16.04 if this changes anything, for example: Maybe git deployment would be easiest?

**My first question is**: I don't expect lot's of traffic (under 1000 a day), and databases are very simple. Only an admin can upload static content, such as posts, images, tags and categories. Essentially a blog format. Where should I store these files? Amazon s3, azure, google, or anything you suggest

**2. Second question is:** Where should I host my web app, and how will it affect where I store my static files?

I'd like to note that I am an entrepreneur doing this on my own so  an inexpensive and simple setup is what I am aiming for as I don't have much experience in server side tech, but willing to learn.

Thank you in advance for your time and sorry if I left out some required information, I'll update the Q as needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. We store our static files on s3 using [s3utils](https://github.com/seperman/s3utils). You should also check out the [this post](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/), it describes how to set up an S3 bucket with the proper permissions.
2. We host our webapps on AWS Ec2 with Nginx and Gunicorn. Check out [How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: I've looked into this, and I'm thinking AWS is my best bet, I really didn't want to have to pull my application from git and place onto a server due to some of the complications that come with it but its nice to have it all with one interface ie: AWS

Comment: You should also take a look at https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa, if you don’t want to deal with servers and maintenance.